# How to use Scrapy and Selenium to get data from a website which uses javascript and php?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am trying to get data from a website which provides information about accidents. I used Scrapy and Selenium for this but it's not working. I am new to this and trying to understand what's going on. I installed both Scrapy and Selenium in a venv. The structure from the website is a bit old and quite hard to understand.

Any help would be appreciated!

I am using Firefox so in the settings I used this:

```
SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'firefox'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('geckodriver.exe')
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=\['-headless'\] \
```

My code looks like this:

```
import scrapy
from selenium.webdriver import firefox
from http.server import executable
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


class MeldingenSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = '112meldingen'

    def start_requests(self):
        settings = get_project_settings
        driver_path = settings.get('SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH')
        driver = firefox(executable_path=driver_path)

        driver.get('http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php')
        xpath = '//*[@id="divContentAlerts"]'
        link_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)


    def parse(self, response):
        articles = response.css('table::attr(id.alerts)')
        for article in articles:
            #if "haven" in article.css('div.title a::text').get():
                yield {
                    'headline': article.css('td.bold a::text').get() ,
                    'timestamp': article.css('td.bold span').get(),
                    'location' : article.xpath('td > td').get()[3]
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  scrape the url with the help of `SeleniumRequest`.

**Script:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
#from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

class MeldingenSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dingen'

    responses = []

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url='http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php',
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        driver = response.meta['driver']
        intial_page = driver.page_source
        self.responses.append(intial_page)
        driver.implicitly_wait(2)

        for resp in self.responses:
            r = Selector(text=resp)
            articles = r.css('table#alerts')
            for article in articles:
            #if "haven" in article.css('div.title a::text').get():
                    yield {
                        'headline': article.css('td.bold a::text').get() ,
                        'timestamp': article.css('td.bold span::text').get().replace('\xa0\xa021',''),
                        'location' : [x.replace('\xa0',' ') for x in article.xpath('.//tr/td[@class="bold center"]/following-sibling::td//text()').getall()][-1]
           

         }
```

You have to change the following instruction from settings.py file

```
# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Middleware

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
}

# Selenium
from shutil import which
SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('chromedriver')
# '--headless' if using chrome instead of firefox
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS = ['--headless']
```

**Output:**

```
{'headline': 'B2 ', 'timestamp': '18:42:39-03-22', 'location': '.'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A1 BAARLE-NASSAU RIT: 37170 (DIRECTE INZET: JA)', 'timestamp': '18:42:22-03-22', 'location': '1220499   Monitor Regionale Ambulancevoorziening Midden- en West-Brabant'}      
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A2 CALLENBURGHPLANTSOEN VOORSC DIRECTE INZET 16185', 'timestamp': '18:42:15-03-22', 'location': '1523185   Ambulance-16-185 Hollands Midden'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A2 DP5 WESTLAND GALGEPAD NAALDW ', 'timestamp': '18:42:00-03-22', 'location': '.'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A2  ', 'timestamp': '18:41:31-03-22', 'location': '0120999   Monitor Regionale Ambulancevoorziening Amsterdam-Amstelland'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A2 ', 'timestamp': '18:41:09-03-22', 'location': '1123128   Ambulance-22-128 Helmond'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A1 AMBU 17104 VERBOOMSTRAAT 3082JC ROTTERDAM ROTTDM BON 40895', 'timestamp': '18:40:43-03-22', 'location': '1420999   Monitor Regionale Ambulancevoorziening Rotterdam-Rijnmond'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A2 BEST RIT: 31448', 'timestamp': '18:40:20-03-22', 'location': '1123124   Ambulance-22-124 Helmond'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A2 MIDDELBURG RIT: 37168 (DIRECTE INZET: JA)', 'timestamp': '18:40:11-03-22', 'location': '1320101   Ambulance-19-101 Goes'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': None, 'timestamp': '18:39:49-03-22', 'location': '1420999   Monitor Regionale Ambulancevoorziening Rotterdam-Rijnmond'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'ONGEVAL MATERIEEL NIEUWE GRACHT HAARLEM', 'timestamp': '18:39:49-03-22', 'location': '0127850   Persinformatie Politie Kennemerland'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': None, 'timestamp': '18:39:48-03-22', 'location': '1420023   Ambulance-17-123 Rotterdam-Rijnmond'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A2 BAARLE-NASSAU RIT: 37167 (DIRECTE INZET: JA)', 'timestamp': '18:39:37-03-22', 'location': '1220646   Ambulance-20-146 Tilburg-Noord'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A1 EINDHOVEN RIT: 31447', 'timestamp': '18:39:29-03-22', 'location': '1123101   
Ambulance-22-101 Eindhoven'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'B1 NIEUWEGEIN 29751', 'timestamp': '18:39:26-03-22', 'location': '0726137   Ambulance-09-137 Amersfoort'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'B1 AMBU 06152 - AALTEN RIT 27711', 'timestamp': '18:38:22-03-22', 'location': '0820152   Ambulance-06-128 Noord- en Oost-Gelderland'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': None, 'timestamp': '18:38:01-03-22', 'location': '0108999   Monitor Brandweer Veiligheidsregio Kennemerland'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': None, 'timestamp': '18:37:12-03-22', 'location': '0520000   Regionaal Proefalarm 
GHOR Drenthe'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A2 DP1 HARNASCHPOLDER VRIJ-HARNASCH DENHZH ', 'timestamp': '18:37:12-03-22', 'location': '.'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A2 11134 RIT 38636 ', 'timestamp': '18:36:30-03-22', 'location': '0126999   Monitor Regionale Ambulancevoorziening Kennemerland'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A1 ZUIDERBEEKWEG 6862EM OOSTERBEEK 41964', 'timestamp': '18:36:28-03-22', 'location': '0920118   Ambulance-07-118 Barneveld'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A2 SOEST 29750', 'timestamp': '18:36:18-03-22', 'location': '0726104   Ambulance-09-148 Utrecht'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A2 RAAMSDONKSVEER RIT: 37166', 'timestamp': '18:36:14-03-22', 'location': '1220626   Ambulance-20-126 Breda-Zuid'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A1 11125 RIT 38634 ELINE VEREPLANTSOEN ZAANDAM', 'timestamp': '18:35:20-03-22', 
'location': '0126999   Monitor Regionale Ambulancevoorziening Kennemerland'}
2022-03-21 23:43:07 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://ftp.112meldingen.nl/index.php>
{'headline': 'A2  ', 'timestamp': '18:35:07-03-22', 'location': '1423397   Ambulance-18-197 Papendrecht'}
```

[seleniumRequest](https://pypi.org/project/py-selenium-scrapy/)